Provide a custom URL to decrypt with KMS
I'm using KMS to encrypt / decrypt data using @aws-crypto/client-node.
I would like to use be able to provide the URL of a custom server to contact for testing purpose. But can't find how to provide this URL using this API. Is it doable ? Here is the current code I use to encrypt/decrypt.

import {
  KmsKeyringNode,
  buildClient,
  CommitmentPolicy,
} from '@aws-crypto/client-node'
   


// Configuration de la politique de commitment
const { encrypt, decrypt } = buildClient(CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_REQUIRE_DECRYPT);

// Identifiant de la clé KMS (remplacez par votre propre clé)
const generatorKeyId = 'arn:aws:kms:my-key';
// Création du keyring KMS
const keyring = new KmsKeyringNode({ generatorKeyId});

// Données à chiffrer
const plaintext = 'Hello, World!';

// Chiffrement des données
async function encryptData() {
  const { result } = await encrypt(keyring, plaintext);
  console.log('Encrypted data:', result);
  return result;
}

// Déchiffrement des données
async function decryptData(encryptedData: any) {
  const { plaintext } = await decrypt(keyring, encryptedData);
  console.log('Decrypted data:', plaintext.toString());
}

// Exécution des fonctions
(async () => {
  const encryptedData = await encryptData();
  await decryptData(encryptedData);
})();


What custom url, a custom KMS server, why? If you want to test it you do not provide a custom server because then you would need to know what calls it will receive and how it is supposed to react, etc. Instead you mock the things you see / interact with, e.g. via https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-client-mock (not sure if that specifically works for crypto)

Yes a custom KMS server (moto) so that I can use the client code without having to actually contact KMS.

This seems to be where it makes the client: https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-javascript/blob/master/modules/kms-keyring/src/kms_client_supplier.ts Looks like it takes a config. Whether that allows you to change the URL for a specific region, I can't tell.
